# Get Holo Timepicker in Android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-timepicker

I am getting the new timepicker using the support library. But I need to show the Holo Style time picker with 30 min time interval.

I am using the following code:

```
 public void showTimePickerDialog(Calendar calendar) {
    selectedCalendarInstance = calendar;
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(activity, R.style.DialogTheme, this, 10, 0, false);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle(null);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

But i need the following style of timepicker

[image]

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I would go for a custom dialog with `TimePicker` as

```
<TimePicker
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"
    ...
    ... 
    ...
/>
```